# Loading a specific video background depending on the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, background

I have a video background, which works fine - I have specified 3 different formats so the video background works in different browsers, however it appears my page is loading all 3 of the video backgrounds at the same time. This is slowing down my page massively!

Just wondering is there a way (using Javascript or jQuery) to detect the browser and load only 1 video background based on what browser is being used?

```
<div class="header-unit">
<div id="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop muted class="fillWidth" id="bgvideo">
    <source src="backgroundvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="backgroundvideo.ogv" type="application/ogg">
    <source src="backgroundvideo.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It shouldn't work that way. The standard dictates that the browser should try each source sequentially (first to last). The moment it finds a video that it can play, it loads just that one.

Check out this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Multiple_sources_example) from Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for your response, so basically only one is loaded at any given time? Even if the browser supports more than 1 format?

Comment: Yeah! You can check the network inspection tool in your browser's dev tools. It should show that only one video is being downloaded.

Comment: @Pranav is correct, though if you do want to be more specific you could check out the `canPlayType()` function for HTML5 video, which allows you to check for support of specific codecs and then only include the one you want